# How do I duplicate an array_rand value across multiple pages?

Tags: php

I have an array filled with random words. My question is, how do I duplicate the value from that `array_rand` across multiple pages?

So, upon refresh, a random value is generated based on my array, and that same value is then echoed on other pages.

How I am going about it now obviously isn't working. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
$elements = array("gold reading glasses","brown sugar","blood","tablet","arrow");
?>

<h1 style="color:red;">
<?php
$generated_element=array_rand($elements,3);
echo $elements[$generated_element[0]]. ", "; echo $elements[$generated_element[1]]. ", "; echo $elements[$generated_element[2]];
?>
</h1>

<h2 style="color:purple;">
<?php
$generated_element=array_rand($elements,3);
echo $elements[$generated_element[0]]. ", "; echo $elements[$generated_element[1]]. ", "; echo $elements[$generated_element[2]];
?>
</h2>
```

This actually worked exactly how I wanted. In the second instance where I wanted the array to generate, I just echoed the variable, and took away the away_rand under the second h2 tag.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['3e-session']=$elements;

$elements = array("gold reading glasses","brown sugar","blood","tablet","arrow", "key", "curtain rod", "dusty", "sour", "igloo", "musket", "ox", "world war II", "cereal", "green sponge", "casket", "kettle", "handle bar", "cursed", "electronic", "hoist", "stewed", "743", "gold plated", "armored truck", "armor", "grudge");
shuffle($elements);
?>


<h1 style="color:red;"><?php
$generated_element=array_rand($elements,3);
echo $elements[$generated_element[0]]. ", "; echo $elements[$generated_element[1]]. ", "; echo $elements[$generated_element[2]];
?></h1>

<h2 style="color:purple;"><?php
echo $elements[$generated_element[0]]. ", "; echo $elements[$generated_element[1]]. ", "; echo $elements[$generated_element[2]];
?></h2>
```

Comment: Use the session to store the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use a SQL database to store the array as a table, instead of trying to make a global array.

Any page can lookup the database and access the table.